# Difference in how a card view is displayed when defined via XML and defined programatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cardview

I have faced a very disturbing problem with using Android's new Card View. 
I defined one card in the my `LinearLayout` in XML and another programatically.

This is how I defined my card view in XML.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/incoming_call_status_card2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

        <include layout="@layout/common_cards_switch_summery"/>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

This is how I did the same in Java.

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
CardView card = new CardView(getActivity());
View.inflate(getActivity(), R.layout.common_cards_switch_summery, card);
layout.addView(card);
```

As you can see both the cards are basically same without any modifications, only thing I am doing in both the situation is inflating the card view with a layout defined in XML (`R.layout.common_cards_switch_summery`).

But the end result I am getting is rather strange.

[image]

It is clearly seen that in the first card, the one that is defined in XML, there is a shadow showing some sort of elevation, but in the second card which I defined in Java doesn't show any shadow at all.

When I set `card_view:cardElevation="5dp"` in XML the elevation is correctly shown. But when I call `card.setCardElevation(5);` in Java there is no elevation at all.

Can someone explain what is happening behind and is there a way for me to achieve the same result that I get in XML while defining it programatically?

*PS - Tested on Lollipop (5.0.1)*

I am importing the same class in Java, which is 
`import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;`

Comment: Use Hierarchy View to see if you can determine what properties are different (besides the margin, which you have on the first but not on the second). Also, rather than `View.inflate()`, try `getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate()`, as `View.inflate()` uses `LayoutInflater.from()` which is almost never the right answer for an activity/fragment. Third, get rid of `addView()`, as that should be superfluous.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that shadow *is* shown under your second `cardView` -- only it got cut by the parent view. The second card doesn't have `marginBottom` defined, that's the difference between those two. Either add the margin or enlarge the parent and see the result!

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can layout in the two ways. Maybe there is no efficient or appropriate way to weigh the performance difference between the `xml` layout and the `java` code. **But for the development convenience's sake, I would decide to use xml rather than java codes.** After all, you have `Palette` to render your `xml` layout file instantly. And there is `Smart Recommends` of attributes of widgets when you writes xml. And you can `drag and drop widgets` too. But can you do this when writing `java` file to layout your widgets? And how many lines will you write when a structure is way too complicated?

Comment: Yes, i do agree with you, but unfortunately in my case i have to create the layout dynamically depending on user's device configuration. So I am defining constant items in the layout in xml and changing ones in java code. I got this problem when trying to do just that.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
cardview.setMaxCardElevation(8);
```

From the [CardView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html) docs:

> If you want to change elevation dynamically, you should call setMaxCardElevation(float) when CardView is initialized.